# Enforce a unique constraint on a business key in single table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table created in SQL Server which defines a business operating in each state. Each business can be in multiple states.

- `Row_ID` is the surrogate key and unique for each row in the table.
- `Business_ID` is the unique value for each `Business_name`.
- `Business_ID` and `State_code` define the relationship that business operates in each state, it's a one-to-many relationship.

| Row_Id | Business_ID | Business_name | State_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Hair Salon | CA |
| 2 | 102 | Nail Salon | CA |
| 3 | 103 | Spa | CA |
| 4 | 101 | Hair Salon | TX |
| 5 | 102 | Nail Salon | TX |
| 6 | 104 | Styling | NY |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dim_Business_Regions]
(
    [Row_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Business_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Business_Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [State_Code] CHAR(2)
)
```

I am trying to enforce a unique constraint on the combination of `Business_ID` and `Business_name` so that there is always one `Business_ID` for each `Business_name`.

Please see the data in the table.

- If we insert a 7th row as `(101, Hair Salon, NY)` - this should be valid row, as 101 is assigned for Hair Salon.
- If we insert a 7th row as `(103, Hair Salon, NY)` - this should be an invalid row and the `INSERT` should fail, as 103 is assigned for Spa and Hair Salon is 101

I couldn't break/Normalize this table into two different tables as there is lot of dependent code that has to be refactored.

Please suggest a solution to enforce this so that I can insert rows with the same Business_ID and same Business name with a different state but insert should fail when I try to insert the reuse the `Business_ID` with a different `Business_Name`.

Comment: So what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? SQL allows you to create constraints on tables?

Comment: _"I couldn't break/Normalize this table into two different tables as there is lot of dependent code that has to be refactored."_ - actually **you can**: that's what `VIEW` objects are for, and _yes_, you can `INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE` a `VIEW` object as though it were a normal table.

Comment: The solution*is* to normalise the design. If that means changing a lot of code, then start making those changes. The fact you need to do this only cements that the lack of normalisation is an issue that needs addressing.

Comment: _"Please suggest a solution to enforce this so that I can insert rows with the same_Business_ID and same Business name with a different state but insert should fail when I try to insert the reuse the Business_ID with a different Business_Name."_ - Even without changing this table to a view, you can still create a new table for `( BusinessId, Business_name )` and have it contain _normalized data_ and have this current table modified so that `( Business_Id, Business_name )` becomes a _composite foreign key_ to the normalized table.

Comment: I just hope a business never needs to change their name with that scenario, @Dai. ;)

Comment: @ThomA `ON UPDATE CASCADE` should handle that, no? Also, the OP might want to consider making this a temporal table too.

Comment: It should, @Dai , but I just have a distrust of cascading (especially as SQL Server 's implementation is quite limited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new table that contains a normalized representation of the Business' data: `dbo.Businesses`.
2. Add a composite `UNIQUE` constraint to `dbo.Businesses`, so a `BusinessId + BusinessName` tuple can be used as an FK into `dbo.Businesses` and to ensure `dbo.Dim_Business_Regions` doesn't contain any anomalous data in those columns.
3. Copy `DISTINCT` data over (with or without `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` depending on if you want `dbo.Businesses` to use `IDENTITY` or a `SEQUENCE` - or some other value source).
4. Wrap it in a `TRANSACTION` with `XACT_ABORT ON`, *as you should*.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Businesses (
    BusinessId   int           NOT NULL /*IDENTITY*/,
    BusinessName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    StateCode    char(2)       NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Businesses PRIMARY KEY ( BusinessId ),

    CONSTRAINT UK_BusinessIdName UNIQUE ( BusinessId, BusinessName )
);

GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION btxn;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Businesses ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.Businesses ( BusinessId, BusinessName, StateCode )
SELECT DISTINCT r.Business_ID, r.Business_Name, r.StateCode FROM dbo.Dim_Business_Regions AS r ORDER BY r.Business_ID;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Businesses OFF;

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Dim_Business_Regions
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BusinessIdName FOREIGN KEY ( Business_ID, Business_Name ) REFERENCES dbo.Businesses ( BusinessId, BusinessName ) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

COMMIT TRANSACTION btxn;
```

Some notes:

- Having both `PK_Businesses` and `UK_BusinessIdName` **is** redundant, but I assume that you'll eventually fix the `dbo.Dim_Business_Regions` table (or convert it to a `VIEW`) in which case you'll only need to `DROP CONSTRAINT UK_BusinessIdName`  while retaining the `PK_Businesses` (which avoids having to rebuild the clustering-index).
- Note that I made `BusinessName` an `nvarchar(100)` column instead of `varchar(100)`. [Always store human-readable names in a Unicode-compatible way](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).
- Consider making `dbo.Businesses` a temporal table - it's been a huge lifesaver overall.